# how do patch the subprocess.run function in python while importing just "run"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest.mock

I imported run from subprocess and I'd like to patch the call to run.
Is it possible to do this without having to import the entire subprocess package?

```
from subprocess import run

run([some_command])

patch.object(subprocess, 'run', return_value=None)
```

This patch doesn't work, but if I change the run command to be subprocess.run, then it works fine. I'm just trying to limit importing things I don't use but would still like to patch the call to the subprocess run function.

Comment: "I imported run from subprocess and I'd like to patch the call to run. Is it possible to do this without having to import the entire subprocess package?"  no, whenever you "import run" you *execute and import* the entire module. That's always how it works

Comment: So just `import subprocess`. This would be the *normal and usual* way of doing things

Comment: If you `import subprocess`, then refer to `subprocess.run`, then `subprocess` _isn't_ something you "don't use" -- you're using it for `run`! More importantly, other Python developers will need to look at where `run` came from on its own, but when they see `subprocess.run` they know exactly what they're seeing; importing the module instead of the individual name improves your code's readability.